# bootstrap .nav-pills backgroundcolor

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm building a website which uses twitter bootstrap.
I want to bring a background color to the .nav-pills navigation bar.
But I have no Ideahow to do this... I did change the color of the buttons though.

How can I change the backgroundcolor of my navigation bar without changing any buttons?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can we see your html/css

Answer (score 2):

Try code like this.

```
    .basicpillsmenu .nav-pills > li > a {
      background-color: #0088cc;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    .basicpillsmenu .nav-pills > li > a:hover {
      background-color: #ff0000;
    }
```

Or

```
&.active > a {
      &,
      &:hover,
      &:focus {
        color: @nav-pills-active-link-hover-color;
        background-color: @nav-pills-active-link-hover-bg;

        .caret {
          border-top-color: @nav-pills-active-link-hover-color;
          border-bottom-color: @nav-pills-active-link-hover-color;
        }
```

Comment: But that would give one the buttons a color right? I need the background of all the buttons toghether. So they will stand out. Or should I make a different <div> for that?